# How do I call a PHP function?

Tags: php, function, authentication, drupal

How do I call this function to my HTML page I where I want the forms to appear?

```
<?php
    function login_bar() {
        global $user;
        if ($user->uid == 0) {
            $form = drupal_get_form('horizontal_login_block');
            return render($form);
        }
        else {
            // You can also integrate other modules such as private
            // messages to show unread / read messages here.
            return '<div id="loginbar"><p>' .
                   t('Welcome back ') .
                   ucwords($user->name) .
                   '<p></div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're hacking your way around Drupal instead of using its full potential. I recommend reading a book or watching some videos about the basics of Drupal site building an theming.

Comment: @deceze The function returns html, so that should be `print login_bar();`.

Answer (score 2):

In the `form` tag of your HTML page:

```
<form type="post" action="test.php">
```

#### File test.php

```
<?php
    function login_bar() {
    }

    // If you want to call the function on some button click:

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        login_bar();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTML page won't process a PHP call. Change your page to page.php and then call `login_bar();`.

Comment: Im trying to customise a drupal 7 template